# как передать параметр в react компонент react + typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

app:

```
import React from 'react'
    import {Main} from './components/main'
    import {Footer} from './components/footer'
    import {propType} from './types/types'
    
    const App: React.FC = () => {
      const operators:propType[] =  [
        {id: 1, name: 'str',img: 'str'},
        {id: 2, name: 'str', img: 'str'},
        {id: 3, name: 'str', img: 'str'}
      ]
      return (<>
              <Main {...operators}/>
              <Footer/>
              </>)
    }
    
    export default App;
          </>)
}

export default App;
```

types.tsx

```
export interface propType {
   id:number
   name: string
   img: string
 }
```

компонент Main в который пытаюсь передать массив данных

```
import React from 'react'
import {propType} from '../types/types'
export const Main: React.FC<propType[]> = (operators) => (
   <div>
      { operators.map(e => <div>{e.id}</div>) }
   </div>
)
```

При передаче не высвечивается не одной ошибки в консоле, на самой странице выводиться только это operators.map is not a function. С одной стороны логично, ведь я из массива преврашаю в объекты, но вот только проблема если я задам operators={operators}, то возникает ошибка.

Сама ошибка:

```
'{ operators: propType[]; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & propType[] & { children?: ReactNode; }'.        
  Property 'operators' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & propType[] & { children?: ReactNode; }'.  TS2322
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react'
import {propType} from '../types/types'

interface typeOperator {
   operators: propType[]
}

export const Main: React.FC<typeOperator> = ({operators}) => (
   <div>
      <div>{
      operators.map(e =>{
         return (<div>{e.name}</div>)
      })
      }</div>
   </div>
)
```

Не понимаю почему, но так заработало. Почему приходиться так делать, чтобы работать?

Comment: так происходит потому что компонент принимает не operators а props а уже внутри props есть operators , в твоем решении ты деструктуризируеш operators